# Accessing response header values in Poltergeist

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, poltergeist

I am writing a simple test to ensure that the "X-Frame-Options" value is set to Deny for my webpage, I use Selenium Webdriver within cucumber but have read that Selenium does not support the retrieval/setting of these headers. I have found small snippets where poltergeist can access these values and have got close when trying things in the console

What I have used so far is

```
@headers = page.driver.network_traffic[1].response_parts.uniq
```

Which in my case returns

```
#<Capybara::Poltergeist::NetworkTraffic::Response:0x00000003a530b8
 @data=
  {"bodySize"=>4752,
   "contentType"=>"text/html",
   "headers"=>
    [{"name"=>"Date", "value"=>"Thu, 23 Jul 2015 06:23:49 GMT"},
     {"name"=>"Server", "value"=>"Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)"},
     {"name"=>"X-Powered-By", "value"=>"PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18"},
     {"name"=>"Set-Cookie", "value"=> "PHPSESSID=sessionidhere; path=/; domain=mydomain; secure; HttpOnly"},
     {"name"=>"Expires", "value"=>"Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"},
     {"name"=>"Cache-Control", "value"=> "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"},
     {"name"=>"Pragma", "value"=>"no-cache"},
     {"name"=>"X-Frame-Options", "value"=>"DENY"},
     {"name"=>"Vary", "value"=>"Accept-Encoding"},
     {"name"=>"Content-Encoding", "value"=>"gzip"},
     {"name"=>"Keep-Alive", "value"=>"timeout=5, max=100"},
     {"name"=>"Connection", "value"=>"Keep-Alive"},
     {"name"=>"Content-Type", "value"=>"text/html"}],
      "id"=>2,
      "redirectURL"=>nil,
      "stage"=>"start",
      "status"=>200,
      "statusText"=>"OK",
      "time"=>"2015-07-23T06:29:19.233Z",
      "url"=>"http://mysite-address.co.uk"}>
```

Is there a way I can just pull out the X Frame Options and assign it to my instance variable? I'm having trouble navigating through the array and key/values.

Or is there a better way of doing this?

### Update

I have got a little further with this

So I have

```
@headers = page.driver.network_traffic[1].response_parts.uniq
@headers[0].headers.find { |h| h['name'] == 'X-Frame-Options' }
# {"name"=>"X-Frame-Options", "value"=>"DENY"}
```

If I then try

```
@headers[0].headers.find { |h| h['name'] == 'X-Frame-Options' }['value']
# "DENY"
```

So I think this is now done, unless anyone can spot something I haven't or have an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

If you have rspec-expectations, could you use:

```
expect(response_headers['X-Frame-Options']).to include('Deny')
```